# sorting,paging,ordering,searching json data response from API server using datatable in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, api, codeigniter, datatables

> i was trying to use paging,sorting,ordering and searching in datatable but i still dont get right reference when data get from json response API. how can sorting,paging,ordering,searching in datatable read json data in API if its not query? im new to this kind of json data from API things. i hope someone can tell me the right things to do it in codeigniter and reference too. thanks!

this is what im doing so far. i already get json data from api to table view but when i use paging etc its just run same process because i know there is no condition for paging etc to process json data. thanks for advice!

this is my function in model for get json data from API

```
function get_filter_order_report($idseri,$idstatus,$orderdate,$nohal,$halaman)
{
    $APIId = '*******';
    $APIKey = '*******';
    $url = '*******';

    $RequestUrl = urlencode($url);
    $RequestUrl = strtolower($RequestUrl);
    $requestHttpMethod = 'get';
    $requestHttpMethod = strtoupper($requestHttpMethod);
    $RequestBodyBase64 = base64_encode(md5('""',true));
    $RequestTimeStamp = time();
    $Nonce = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10));
    $SignatureRawData = $APIId.''.$requestHttpMethod.''.$RequestUrl.''.$RequestTimeStamp.''.$Nonce.''.$RequestBodyBase64;
    $SignatureBase64 = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $SignatureRawData, $APIKey, 'true'));      
    $dataSignature = $APIId.':'.$SignatureBase64.':'.$Nonce.':'.$RequestTimeStamp;
    $AuthString = base64_encode($dataSignature);    

    $data = new stdClass;   
    $proxy = '********';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization : amx '.$AuthString)
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $var = json_decode($result);
    echo json_encode($var->Records);    
}
```

and my controller now just get data there is no condition for datatable server side paging,sorting,searching and ordering

```
function show_order_report()
{
    if($_POST){
        $arr = array('IdSeri' => $this->input->post('seriid'),
                     'Status' => $this->input->post('statid'),
                     'TglPemesanan' => $this->input->post('orderdate')
                    );
        $halaman = 10;
        $nohal = 1;
        $idseri = $arr['IdSeri'];
        $idstatus = $arr['Status'];
        $orderdate = $arr['TglPemesanan'];
        echo $this->Pemesanan_model->get_filter_order_report($idseri,$idstatus,$orderdate,$nohal,$halaman);
    }else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">parent.content.location = "'.base_url().'default"</script>';
    }
}
```

and this is my datatable ajax serverside script in view

```
function filterOrder(){
        var token = document.getElementById('token').value;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("div#form-wrap").show();
            var postData = {
                <?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?> : token,
                seriid: $('#seriid').val(),
                statid: $('#statid').val(),
                orderdate: $('#orderdate').val()
            };
            var code = {<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?> : token,};
            var tglorder = formatDate('TglPemesanan');
            var table = $('#orders').DataTable({
                "responsive"   : true,
                "processing"   : true,
                "serverSide"   : true,
                "destroy": true,
                "paging":   true,
                "searching": true,
                "ajax"   : {
                    url : "<?=base_url();?>SBNReport.jsp/show_order_report",
                    type: "post",
                    data: postData,
                    dataSrc: ''
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "NamaInvestor" },
                    { "data": "KodePemesanan" },
                    { "data": "Seri" },
                    { "data": "Sid" },
                    { "data": "KodeBilling" },
                    { "data": "Nominal" },
                    { "data": "Status" },
                    { "data": "TglPemesanan" },
                    { "data": "NTPN" },
                    {
                        sortable: false,
                        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                        var buttonID = full.KodePemesanan;
                        return '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-sm" href="javascript:getTransaction(\''+buttonID+'\')">Detail</a>';
                        }
                    },
                ],
                //Set column definition initialisation properties.
                "columnDefs": [
                    { 
                        "targets": [ 9 ], //last column
                        "orderable": false, //set not orderable
                        "searchable" : false,
                    },
                    {
                        "targets" : 7,
                        render : function(data){
                        //Here you should call the date format function:
                        return formatDate(data);
                        }
                    }
                ],        
                "language": {
                    "lengthMenu": "<?= $this->lang->line('dt_show') ?> _MENU_ <?= $this->lang->line('dt_record') ?> <?= $this->lang->line('dt_per_page') ?>",
                    "zeroRecords": "<?= $this->lang->line('dt_empty') ?>",
                    "info": "<?= $this->lang->line('dt_show') ?> <?= $this->lang->line('dt_page') ?> _PAGE_ <?= $this->lang->line('dt_of') ?> _PAGES_ <?= $this->lang->line('dt_page') ?>",
                    "infoEmpty": "<?= $this->lang->line('dt_empty') ?>",
                    "infoFiltered": "<?= $this->lang->line('dt_filtered') ?> <?= $this->lang->line('dt_of') ?> _MAX_ <?= $this->lang->line('dt_record') ?>)",
                    "search": "<?= $this->lang->line('dt_search') ?>",
                    "processing": "<?= $this->lang->line('dt_processsing') ?>",
                },
                "initComplete": function( oSettings ) {
                    parent.setIframeHeight('content');
                },
                "drawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
                    parent.setIframeHeight('content');
                },
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: What have you done to debug? Are you getting any errors? You should be evaluating the code and variables at different points. How would we know what is wrong? You can't just throw up a bunch of code and expect anyone to know what's going on.

Comment: @BrianGottier no errors. when i use sorting,paging,searching,ordering its just run same process in controller. i told you i just need advice for doing it not to fix my code. i just post my code to share what im doing so far. i already get json data from API but in controller i still not doing any process for paging etc. thanks for remind me by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genaraly, datatables send a number of parameters to a source (i.e. your Ajax url) in a request (You can also check in the network tab by <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>).

I dont know about JSP which is your server script but 
[Check this](https://gist.github.com/jjb3rd/3156545) for PHP server side code.

First print all the values in the request.

Look from line no. 31, which is for `paging.Datatable` and automatically send the limit value for the query when you click next/prev/any page number of the pagination.

I made changes to it for multiple tables, different columns, and extra conditions by passing extra parameters in the request.

Hope you get the idea.